# Problem binding DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Am trying to bind data to a dropdown list on pageload based on a condition. Code explains further below.

```
public partial class AddExhibit : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string adminID, caseIDRetrieved;

    DataSet caseDataSet = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter caseSqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    string strConn = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CMSSQL3ConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        adminID = Request.QueryString["adminID"];
        caseIDRetrieved = Request.QueryString["caseID"];

        if (caseIDRetrieved != null)
        {
            CaseIDDropDownList.Text = caseIDRetrieved;
            //CaseIDDropDownList.Enabled = false;

        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                CreateDataSet();
                DataView caseDataView = new DataView(caseDataSet.Tables[0]);
                CaseIDDropDownList.DataSource = caseDataView;
                CaseIDDropDownList.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string script = "<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>";
            }

        }


    }
```

The CreateDataset method that is called in the if..else statement is contains the following code.

```
private void CreateDataSet()
    {
        SqlConnection caseConnection = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        caseSqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select CaseID FROM Cases", caseConnection);
        caseSqlDataAdapter.Fill(caseDataSet);
    }
```

However when I load the page and as usual the condition that is supposed to bid the data is met, the gridview decides to displays as follows...
[image]

IS IT ME OR ITS THE DATAGRID?...??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to bind a combo box to a Data View. You're not a *dumb*, but it's definitely your fault!!

The problem behind this is that what you bind (`DataView`) is a collection of `DataRowView`, which is a multi-dimensional entity (ie. a table) when combo boxes are unidimensional.

The reason why you get this is that combo boxes use the `ToString()` method to render the object they are bound to. So, making it all together, you are binding the combo box to a collection of rows, each element of combo box is bound to a row, which is not an entity that can be rendered as a string (as it contains more columns **in general**, even if in your case you have one column).

## Solution 1 (bad, requires little more coding and processing)

Transform the DataView in a `IEnumerable<string>`, you'll get it rendered immediately!

## Solution 2 (good)

Acting on the combo box, set the `DataTextField` property to `CaseID`

I wanted to tell you about both solutions

Comment: Hmmm....very helpful comment...i get where am going wrong. but am not sure how to set the datatextfield. IF you could elaborate a little bit further...

Comment: Ah!...i figured it out... CaseIDDropDownList.DataTextField = "CaseID";...So i wasnt dumb afterall...:D

Comment: After you set the CaseIDDropDownList.DataSource, set the DataTextField property.  CaseIDDropDownList.DataTextField = "CaseID";

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, that isn't a DataGridView. Secondly, you need to set its DataTextField property.

Comment: Okay..guess i lost my temper a bit there and mentioned gridview instead of dataset or dataview. Thanks Pete for reminding me that anger does not get us far. SO where do you suggest i set the datatextfield property? if you could give an example of it being in use that would be very helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I left that unspecified because it's a matter of preference. You can do it also in the .aspx/.ascx file, as <asp:DropDownList DataTextField="CaseID" ... />

Answer (score 0):

You need to set DataTextField property of your ComboBox.

Comment: Emmm....deadlock..? i am a bit confused. that string of code you asked me to change is actually passing values transferred from the previous page to the current page so if i changed that "caseID" to "CaseID" i guess i wouldnt be able to fetch whats being transferred in the URL...What do you say?

Comment: I am sorry for the miss-leading comment. I didn't read the code well. I actually thought you are giving wrong case parameters (caseID) to DataTextField of the ComboBox, I will edit the answer now.